# Permalink structure /page/page/cpt-post gives 404 with pagination

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to achieve this permalink structure:

- Page "about-us"

  - Page "stories"

    - Post (story CPT) "post-title"

The page "stories" is a custom page template that shows archive for custom post type "story", it needs to be a page template so I can edit the content, and should also have pagination for posts.

So *domain.com/about-us/stories/* should show "story" CPT archive with pagination and *domain.com/about-us/stories/story-title/* should show a single story.

I seem to get either the archive page pagination, or the post permalink to work, but not both.

If I set my CPT rewrite like

```
'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'                  => __('about-us/stories', 'text-domain'),
        'with_front'            => false,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => false,
    )
```

The post permalink works just as expected, and I can follow a link to domain.com/about-us/stories/story-title/ and that's all fine, but the pagination on domain.com/about-us/stories/ won't work and gives a 404 error when changing page. If I set my CPT rewrite like

```
'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'                  => __('stories', 'text-domain'),
        'with_front'            => false,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => false,
    )
```

the pagination on archive page works, but the post permalinks are now domain.com/stories/story-title and not domain.com/**about-us**/stories/story-title/

I also tried playing with `add_rewrite_tag` and `add_rewrite_rule` but can't seem to work my way around this problem. Is this permalink structure possible or should do I just need to settle for different url structure for single posts?

Comment: In your second rewrite rule change 'with_front' => true and try again. Make sure you save your permalinks again.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as my posts permalink is set to domain.com/news/%postname%/ so setting "with_front"  to true would make my permalink structure domain.com/news/stories/story-title

Comment: Is there a reason you made stories a page rather than using the post type archive WordPress generates automatically?

Comment: Yes, there's some content on the page before the post list that needs to be editable by client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working with a little help from [Debug This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-this/) and some little hints from similar questions. At least so far, after some quick testing, I haven't come across any negative side effects.

The problem, if I understood correctly, is that if I have my cpt rewrite set to same slug as my archive page `/about-us/stories`, WP rewrites pagination requests `/about-us/stories/page/n/` to a CPT named "page" which in this case returns 404.

To fix this I needed to make a [custom rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to check if we're querying for a page number and rewrite it accordingly:

```
function wpse288130_rewrite_rules() {

    add_rewrite_rule('^(.?.+?)/page/(\d)$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');

}
add_action('init', 'wpse288130_rewrite_rules');
```

Where the regex's first capturing group `(.?.+?)` catches the page name `about-us/stories` and the second group `(\d)` catches any digit after `/page/`

In the second parameter of `add_rewrite_rule` we tell WP to rewrite this as `index.php?pagename=about-us/stories&paged=[page number]`

Third parameter 'top' tells WP to prioritize this rewrite above default rewrites.